# Query String in Elasticsearch 6.4.3

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know the difference between these queries

```
{
  "size": "1",
  "from": "0",
  "track_scores": true,
  "sort": [
    {
      "employee_id": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "content",
            "title"
          ],
          "query": "\"Macro Medium\""
        }
      }
}
```

When compared to this code

```
{
  "size": "1",
  "from": "0",
  "track_scores": true,
  "sort": [
    {
      "employee_id": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": [
            "content",
            "title"
          ],
          "query": "Macro Medium"
        }

}
```

I want to know the difference between "query": "\"Macro Medium\"" and "query": "Macro Medium" in Elasticsearch 6.4.3. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `"` is also a character that you might want to search so when you use it like `\"` in a query, you actually escape it. So, the difference is that when using `\"`, you actually force for those quotation marks to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query string according to your analyzer (default is standard analyzer), analyze your string and break it in two word (Macro, Medium). then as default, use this two word on should term query (OR). also you can change it to AND ("default_operator" :"AND"). 
with \"phrase\" you force the elastic to not break the string.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: are you sure of this? can you please provide some document regarding this.

Comment: @sid8491  
The default operator used if no explicit operator is specified. For example, with a default operator of OR, the query capital of Hungary is translated to capital OR of OR Hungary, and with default operator of AND, the same query is translated to capital AND of AND Hungary. The default value is OR.

Comment: what if i want to include quotation marks in the search query?

Comment: @sid8491 Analyze the query string.

The query string QUICK! is passed through the standard analyzer, which results in the single term quick. Because we have just a single term, the match query can be executed as a single low-level term query.

Comment: so you cant use standard analyzer. (elastic would not index quotation marks with standard analyzer)